# Can Nagle's algorithm be disabled when using HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, android

I am using HttpUrlConnection to communicate with a server. Latency is very important and after analyzing tcpdump logs with WireShark I've come to the conclusion that Nagle's algorithm is a problem.

I know that Nagle's algorim can be disabled by setting the TCP_NODELAY option however I haven't been able to figure out how to do that when using HttpUrlConnection ...  is this possible ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I note that [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) allows you to do this via [setTcpNoDelay()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay%28boolean%29).

So if you can either get access to the underlying socket, or (unfortunately) recode the HTTP URL connection, you may be in luck.

A better solution may be to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org). [HttpConnectionParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html) exposes this info (I confess I'm not famuiliar with Android so I don't know if this option is available to you)